# jquery block of code will be applied to the new field added by user

Tags: jquery

My block of jquery code is working on the existing field for address, but if user adds a new field for extra address, jquery code is no longer working even the selector I used is for class.

this is my block of code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   const searchInput = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');    
   loadGooglePlaces(searchInput, {
      types: ['geocode'],
  });
});
```

I need to make sure that this block of code will be applied to another address field that the user added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: It's hard to tell from the small amount of code exactly what's *"no longer working"*.  Normally this would be fixed by event delegation (see link in comment above) - but that won't help if the issue is in `loadGooglePlaces`.   Please be specific.   You can probably fix this by re-calling `loadGooglePlaces(newInput` when you add your new input; if you include that code, we might be able to help.